# Implicitly defines - conflict (Auto generated private field)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Okay, so I stumbled upon an auto generated private member I wasn't aware of.

I know that if you have a property named e.g. **`P`** then the name **`get_P`** is reserved for the getter method and the name **`set_P`** is reserved for the setter method.

But what I didn't know was that the name **`_P`** is also reserved. It seems that this only applies to properties (not `ReadOnly` / `WriteOnly`) and fields defiend as `WithEvents`.

```vb
Public Class Test

    Public Property p As Object

    Public WriteOnly Property pW() As Object
        Set(value As Object)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property pR() As Object
        Get
        End Get
    End Property

    Public f As Object
    Public WithEvents fWE As Object

    Private _p As Object
    Private _pW As Object
    Private _pR As Object
    Private _f As Object
    Private _fWE As Object

End Class
```

The above class will produce the following errors:

> **1)** *property 'p' implicitly defines '_p', which conflicts with a member of the same name in class 'Test'.*
>
> **2)** *WithEvents variable 'fWE' implicitly defines '_fWE', which conflicts with a member of the same name in class 'Test'.*

If I remove all the fields named `_{name}` and return all members (including `NonPublic` fields) of type `Test` one can clearly see the auto generated members.

```
.cctor (Constructor)
.ctor (Constructor)
__ENCAddToList (Method)
__ENCList (Field)
_fWE (Field)  <------------------------------- *2
_p (Field) <---------------------------------- *1
Equals (Method)
f (Field)
Finalize (Method)
fWE (Property)
get_fWE (Method)
get_p (Method)
get_pR (Method)
GetHashCode (Method)
GetType (Method)
MemberwiseClone (Method)
p (Property)
pR (Property)
pW (Property)
set_fWE (Method)
set_p (Method)
set_pW (Method)
ToString (Method)
```

So does anybody know why these fields are generated and/or their purpose?

Comment: an auto generated property creates the _P variable as the backing field which allows you to reference it locally (`P = someValue` or `_p = someValue`) just like any other property.  there really isnt much difference in the code between an auto and manually implemented property.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks! Do you know the purpose of having a backing field for an auto generated field?

Comment: I have used it internally in classes where P might be changed to ReadOnly so there is almost nothing to change when you do change it.  There might also be reasons related to inheritance but I cant think of a scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using auto generated properties.  Those fields are automatically generated  as the backing fields for the property.  See section 9.7.4 of the VB 10 Lanugage Spec:

**9.7.4 Automatically Implemented Properties**

If a property omits declaration of any accessors, an implementation of the 
property will be automatically supplied unless the property is declared in 
an interface or is declared MustOverride.  Only read/write properties with no 
arguments can be automatically implemented; otherwise, a compile-time error 
occurs.

***An automatically implemented property x, even one overriding another 
property, introduces a private local variable _x with the same type as the 
property. If there is a collision between the local variable's name and 
another declaration, a compile-time error will be reported.***

The 
automatically implemented property’s Get accessor returns the value of the 
local and the property’s Set accessor that sets the value of the local.

For example, the declaration:

```
Public Property x() As Integer
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
Private _x As Integer 
Public Property x() As Integer 
    Get 
        Return _x 
    End Get 
    Set (value As Integer) 
        _x = value 
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Thanks! That explains why I've never seen this before because I always create my own private fields for each property. Do you know the  purpose of having a backing field when a `Field` is defined as `WithEvents`?